# Press Button on ViewController which pushes to TabBarController with UINavigation Bar?

Tags: ios, storyboard, tabbar, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently developing an app that I plan to distribute soon, however I am having trouble with my storyboard configuration. What I want is to have a view which displays 4 buttons on it and when one button is pressed it pushes to a different view with at a TabBar installed on it. I wanted to know how to do this, the app STRAVA has the exact same thing as I want. Do I have to do this programatically and if so how, or should I do this in a Storyboard, and if so how? Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks